# Star-Delta starter connection of motors

Tags: motor, y-to-delta

The Star Delta Starter is a very common type of starter and is used extensively.

It is said that a star delta is used for a cage motor designed to run normally on the delta connected stator winding.

So If a motor is designed to run normally on the star connection, can we use the start delta starter with it?

How can we know if a motor can be connected in star delta starter from the motor nameplate?

Comment: Seems like you copied this question from CircuitGlobe.com. If not, that site has an article explaining your question.

Comment: [The Star Delta Starter is a very common type of starter and is used extensively... A star delta is used for a cage motor designed to run normally on the delta connected stator winding](https://circuitglobe.com/star-delta-starter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motor manufacturers have different ways of marking the nameplate, but the information should be there.Two voltages with the proper ratio and an indication of star (or y) and delta should be marked. The low voltage is the running voltage and the high voltage is 1.732 times the low voltage. When you start, the low voltage is applied to the high voltage connection. That limits the starting current and the starting torque. Here is a nameplate example:

[image]